# Applications of semantic web/ontology in informational retrieval?

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, semantic-web, information-retrieval, ontology

What are the uses of Semantic Web in the information Retrieval. Semantic Web here i mean, the structured created like DBPedia, Freebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have integrated information in RDF with Lucene in several projects and i think a lot of the value you can get from the integration is that you can go beyond the simple keyword search that Lucene would normally enable.  That opens up possibilities for full text search over your RDF information, but also semantically enriched full-text search.

In the former case, there is no 'like' operator in SPARQL, and the regex function while similarly capable to the SQL like, is not really tractable to evaluate against a dataset of any appreciable size.  However, if you're able to use lucene to do the search instead of relying on regex, you can get better scale and performance out of a single keyword search over your RDF.

In the latter case, if the query engine is integrated with the lucene text/rdf index, think [LARQ](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/larq/), (both [Jena](http://jena.apache.org) and [Stardog](http://stardog.com) suppot this), you can do far more complex semantic searches over your full-text index.  Queries like 'get all the genres of movies where there are at least 10 reviews and the reviews contain the phrase "two thumbs up"'  That's difficult to swing with a lucene index, but becomes quite trivial in the intersection of Lucene & SPARQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DBpedia in Information Retrieval, since it has the structured information from Wikipedia.
Since Wikipedia has knowledge of almost every topic of interest in terms of articles, categories, info-boxes that is being used in the information retrieval systems to extract the meaningful information in the form of triples i.e. Subject, Predicate & Object.

You can query the information via SPARQL using the following endpoint:[Endpoint to query the information from DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql)